ASP.NET Web API 4 authentication with Okta JWT: HttpContext.User suddenly has 2 identities
I am trying to set up Okta authentication for a SPA app with .NET 4 Web API backend. The following code has been added to the startup.cs file(the TokenHandler option is important as we need to issue custom claims for authorization), and the application is able to load properly:
       var authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:OrgUri"];
       var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
           authority + "/oauth2/default/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server",
           new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(),
           new HttpDocumentRetriever()
       );

   var discoveryDocument = Task.Run(() => configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
       IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

       app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
          new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
          {
              AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
              TokenHandler = new OktaJwtSecurityTokenHandler(),
              TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
              {
                  ValidAudience = "api://default",
                  ValidIssuer = authority + "/oauth2/default",
                  IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, identifier, parameters) =>
                  {
                      return discoveryDocument.SigningKeys;
                  }
              }
          });

However, for some reason ASP.NET Identity does not seem to work correctly following this change. I am able to issue custom claims, but they are not assigned to HttpContext.Current.User properly. Instead, when I inspect this object, I find that there are 2 identities for the ClaimPrincipal, while the claims were issued to the second identity which is not being used at all.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to fix this problem by removing a duplicate identity? I tried to add a call to config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication() but it doesnt work at all, instead it fails authentication with 401 error each time I run/debug the app.

Do you have more than one authentication middlewares? I've seen two Identities when trying to combine more than one auth middleware. Also, make sure (if you haven't) to disable the default host authentication mechanism to avoid adding multiple identities to the ClaimsPrincipal.

@CoreySutton I did try to add a call config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication() to disable the default host authentication mechanism, and then everything ends up as 401 error.

seems like there is an issue with the auth then where the default is needed to authorize api calls. i'd root that out and you might find the solution to your double identity issue as well
